# How to fix "Unable to connect to Samsung Pay temporarily"?

Tags: samsung-pay, samsung-galaxy-a8-2018

I'm trying to setup Samsung Pay on a new Galaxy A8 2018 but I get this error message every time, even after re-installing Samsung Pay and resetting the phone as well as clearing Samsung Pays data.

> **Connection Error**
>
> Unable to connect to Samsung Pay temporarily. Try again later.

I've looked through the Samsung Account data and entered all I could.

The phone has "Magyar" as default region when I start it, could that be it?
I don't have any SIM card in it but when I try putting one in I still get the same error message.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samsung Pay requires a SIM card to work, and it requires it on the first boot.

My solution was to **put the SIM card in and then reset* the phone**.

When it started with a SIM card in it, I saw "Samsung pay Sweden" pinned to the home screen (Swedish SIM card). ***It then worked flawlessly.***

---

Why isn't this bug fixed yet one could ask, but there you have it.

---

Why didn't I have a SIM card in when I first booted it? I had to order a new micro SIM from my operator which took a week to get delivered.

---

** Reset it to factory defaults, wipe it clean. I guess you have everything in the cloud anyway.*